# Why won't any classList shim work in IE9 as I'm using it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, shim

[Here's a Codepen thing.](http://codepen.io/75th/pen/naiLH)

I'm using `classList.add` and `classList.remove` in my little map locator thing. (I have to, it seems, because className doesn't work right with SVG elements.) You can see how I'm using them on lines 184 and 194 of the JS in the codepen. IE9 doesn't support classList, so I've tried a number of different shims ([one](http://purl.eligrey.com/github/classList.js), [two](https://gist.github.com/1381839), [three](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList)).

None of them seems to work in IE9 with my code. They do work if I load them in [a test fiddle with only a line or two of code](http://jsfiddle.net/75th/p3z3K/), but not in my full thing as it exists (and I haven't refactored it into something nice and object-oriented yet so it's pretty terrible).

My first thought was the problem is somehow because I'm getting at the DOM elements with `jQuery().get()`. But in the IE9 console, I can do `document.getElementById` and it fails just as much.

What's actually going on here?

Comment: I haven't read all the hundreds of lines in that Pen, but you should note that a class on a SVG element is not the same as a class on a regular DOM node, they are very different, with different properties etc. so a shim for regular DOM nodes is not certain to work with SVG nodes.

Comment: I thought of that, but the shim doesn't work in IE9 for regular HTML elements, either.

Comment: @adeneo …Or so I thought. It turns out I was relying on the IE Developer Tools to not suck. When you change a class in IE, the HTML inspector does not show the change the way it does in other browsers; you have to fetch the value in the console to see the changes. So this really was due to the difference between SVGElement and HTMLElement; if you post an answer to that effect, I'll accept it, and edit it with my working code.